# Taking a path from stdin and using it as argument to readFile

Tags: shell, haskell

As a learning strategy, I tried to modify Prelude `interact` function.

`test.hs` contents

```hs
interact' :: (String -> String) -> IO ()
interact' f = do
  path <- getContents
  s <- readFile path
  putStr (f s)

main :: IO ()
main = interact' id
```

`test.txt` contents

```
Hello World
```

Calling `echo "test.txt" | runhaskell test.hs` doesn't display `Hello World`. Am I overlooking something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo "test.txt"` produces the string `test.txt\n`, and you don't have a file called `test.txt\n`, just one called `test.txt`. Either use `getLine` instead of `getContents` in Haskell to not get the newline, or `printf` instead of `echo` in the shell to not emit the newline in the first place.